# Xamarin Listview binding to ObservableCollection of normal class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been supplied with a `Book` class which is not implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and I can't change it. I have a collection of `Book` which I want to show in a `ListView` in Xamarin. So:

```
public class BookListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    private void TestAction()
    {
        Books[1].Name = "New Name";
        //Here I need to inform the list to refresh
    }
}
```

Now I bind this `Books` to my `ListView.ItemsSource`. How can I inform the `ListView` to refresh? I have tried placing `OnPropertyChanged("Books");` where the comment is but not luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you try `OnPropertyChanged("Books");` this is used for notify the list that the count of the elements has been changed and not the elements themselves .

As you cannot implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the model level, the trick is to when you modify a cell in the list in your case:

1. Remove the element you want to modify
2. Call `OnPropertyChanged("Books");` so the list would be refreshed
3. Add the element you want to modify with the new data
4. Call `OnPropertyChanged("Books");` so the list would be refreshed with the cell updated.

As you might guess this solutiom might solve your problem but performance wise is bad , since you have the viewlist has to be redrawn twice. So if the class **Book** is changable frequently then I would say that you have to change it to make it implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Or you might have a middle copy of **Book** class that would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has an instance of **Book** that you refer to its properties from the riplica class. 
You can use **Automapper** to help you with that by the way if you have many classes to deal with

Comment: Thanks for the response. It will work but not a professional thing to do. A better solution would be to have a replica of the `Book` that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use AutoMapper or similar to converting types but these are workarounds. I need robust solution if available.

Comment: Yes that would work too , but i thought that it could be long process but then you mentioned AutoMapper . So if you think it is a correct answer please mark it so the others can find it too :)